# Use jQuery.data to get a boolean from a dom element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

According to [jQuery's .data() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/data/#data2) you can use the .data() method to `data` prefixed attributes from a dom element. For example:

```
{# Include jquery.... #}
<div id='mydiv' data-foo='bar'></div>
<script>
    var foo = $('#mydiv');
    foo.data('foo');   // == 'bar'
</script>
```

That said, I'm curious how you set and pass boolean values in these dom objects. As far as I know, this does **not** work:

**Throws a javascript error:**

```
{# Include jquery.... #}
<div id='mydiv' data-foo=false></div>
```

**Sets a string instead of a boolean:**

```
{# Include jquery.... #}
<div id='mydiv' data-foo='false'></div>
<script>
    var foo = $('#mydiv');
    foo.data('foo');   // == 'false'
</script>
```

So, how do I set boolean values in the dom? *Or*, do I have to convert these string values to booleans in my javascript (which seems lame)?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zerkms/pnsfL/ - here I get the boolean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example just works :-)

http://jsfiddle.net/zerkms/pnsfL/

https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/data.js#L335

```
data = data === "true" ? true :
data === "false" ? false :
data === "null" ? null :
jQuery.isNumeric( data ) ? parseFloat( data ) :
    rbrace.test( data ) ? jQuery.parseJSON( data ) :
    data;
```

So jquery guesses the boolean, null, numeric types and JSON (!!! that's new for me)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use type-conversion. `data-foo` could be set to `1 = true` or `0 = false` and use this example: http://jsfiddle.net/QAkQW/

Answer (score 0):

Every attempt is made to convert the string to a JavaScript value (this includes **booleans**, numbers, objects, arrays, and null) otherwise it is left as a string.

You should simply be able to do something like this: (which is what you are doing)

```
<div data-role="page" data-last-value="43" data-hidden="true" data-options='{"name":"John"}'></div>

$("div").data("hidden") === true;
```

Look at the example code for `.data()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want boolean value, you could just do it by **Set or Not Set this attribute.**

But it seems that jQuery.data has already get boolean value for you.